# Is it typical to say "How to get rich and don't go crazy"?

Tags: idioms

In my native language sometimes we use humorous titles of books, articles, tutorials, etc among the lines of:

> "How to get rich and don't go crazy?"

I thought that I meet with it once or twice in english too. But now I did search in google and [Corpus Of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and all I found is only one page titled:

> How to Follow Your Interests and Don't Go Crazy or Broke

So it seems that it isn't nearly as popular in english as I thought.

Is such form used in English occasionally or I'm totally off-track? Is there any valid replacement for that?

Comment: I would use the gerund form; i.e., *How to Get Rich **Without Going Crazy***. Related Google search: ["without going crazy"](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=%22without%20going%20crazy%22)

Comment: To match "don't go crazy", the beginning of the phrase should be "Get rich (and don't go crazy).  However, the answers below are more elegant in their interpretation of your phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such titles are frequent in English, too, but they are phrased a little differently:

> How to X Without Ying

For example (the first is a 1950s musical, the rest are from the first page of a Google Books search on ["how to" without])

> How to Succeed in Business Without Really Trying
>   How to Succeed in School Without Really Learning
>   How to Be a Language Snob Without Being a Jerk
>   How to Do Homework Without Throwing Up
>   How to Say No Without Feeling Guilty

Comment: And *How to Do Nothing with Nobody All Alone by Yourself* - no *without* involved, but a great read for older children.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is it not popular it is, at least to my mind,  ungrammatical. A correct form would be

> "How to get rich and *not* go crazy?".

or as StoneyB mentions

> "How to get rich without going crazy?".

*Don't* is an imperative, it is used for giving commands like *don't touch that!* It makes no sense to include it in a title like yours, it sounds like the author started to write a title and was distracted by someone, turned to talk to them and told them not to o crazy.